# Centos 7 with facebook php-sdk4 - Network is unreachable

Tags: centos, ipv6, php5

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Sometimes, it works and sometimes I get this error in the error log:

```
Exception: Failed to connect to 1a02:1234:f000:4:face:b00c:0:1: Network is unreachable FacebookCurlHttpClient.php
```

So, I decided to disable the IPv6 in `sysctl.conf`
I added the following lines.

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

And then I executed this line

```
sysctl -p
```

Again, I am facing this error in error log.

Comment: Keep in mind that disabling IPv6 is never the solution to a problem. In some situations it may be a useful step to narrow down the source of a problem, but that is about it. You are not done fixing the problem until you have enabled IPv6 again and things are working. In your case there are other clues to look for. First of all, you need to figure out which domain name, the library is trying to access. The IP address in itself is not helping a lot. You might have to look at the mentioned source file to find out what the domain name is.

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment, we can learn something from the IP address. The IP address is in a reserved block, so it is quite clear that the library is attempting to connect to an incorrect IP address. So you need to figure out where it got that IP address from. This leads me back to the same conclusion as before though. Until you have identified the domain name it is resolving, you will get no closer to fixing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This means your app was unable to connect to facebook over IPv4 and since most systems will return an AAAA record even if you don't have IPv6 configured on your system, php ends up trying the next address to connect to which happens to be IPv6.  I suspect if you disabled IPv6 via the means mentioned above, you're going to have other errors in your logs now.